# How to combine combine dialog window and rich text editor in Prototype.js?

Tags: text, modal-dialog, editor, prototypejs

I have several textareas on my page and to save some space I want to open the text editor within a modal dialog when a user clicks on a textarea. What I did so far:

Imported following libraries (and css):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.3/scriptaculous.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="protoplasm.js"></script>
```

Initialized the protoplasm editor and the modal dialog:

```
Protoplasm.use('dialog');
Protoplasm.use('rte').transform('textarea.overlay_textarea');
```

and then tried to run it:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function () {
    $$("textarea:not(.overlay_textarea)").each(function (el) {
        el.observe('click', respondToClick);
        function respondToClick(event) {
            var element = Event.element(event);
            //var text = element.value;
            var text = $F(element);
            console.log(text);
            var content = '<textarea class="overlay_textarea">' + text + '</textarea>';
            console.log(content);

            function showDialog() {
                var d = new Dialog.HTML(content);
                d.show();
            }
            showDialog();                        
        }
    });
});
```

HTML is simply:

```
<textarea id="h1_de_1" class="cright_txtarea" >tfzduto</textarea>
```

That opens a new textarea dialog with the text from the clicked textarea. But the editor won't open. I also tried to initialize the editor after the showDialog-call but that didn't work. Do I need a special event listener or is it just not possible to combine those two elements?

P.S.: Sorry that there is no jsfiddle but the protoplasm library contains many subdirectories so I'm not able to import it there.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create an element by inserting it and retain a reference to the inserted element in the same line. This can lead to timing errors. More long-hand, but a more reliable method is to create the element behind the scenes with Element.new, then insert it, then do whatever you like with it later. I have built an editor similar to what you propose here, and it does work. One more tip: see if your outer loop is actually capturing any elements. Add console.log(el) as the third line of your snippet, and see if you are actually getting anything.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! But I was so frustrated working with Prototype.js that I switched to jQuery and Tiny MCE because I know the language better ;) No I try to run something like that: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:TinyMCE_in_a_jQuery_UI_dialog and use jQuery's $.noConflict(); Hope it will work :D